# Making a tag into the new trunk in Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control, tags, trunk

We have a situation where we need to take a tag of our project and make it the new trunk.  We have taken the existing trunk and made it into a separate branch.  My question is this - once we made a branch of the trunk, can we just delete the trunk and then copy the tag in question into the trunk?  Is there a safer way of doing it?

Any advice would be greatly appreciative!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that without any risk, because that operation is also logged by SVN so if then you need to rollback something, you can.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use [svn move](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html) (which basically does a copy and delete).

```
svn move /path/to/repo/tag/foo /path/to/repo/trunk
```